# delete cloned file in a remote hadoop cluster

Tags: git, hadoop, hdfs, git-clone

I created a repository on GitHub and cloned it to a remote hadoop cluster `git clone <link of my repository>`.
Now I want to remove this repository from hadoop cluster. How can I do that?
I tried `cd hadoop fs -rm -r <my repository in cluster>`, but it said:

> No such file or directory

Comment: git clone does not upload something to hdfs... Just ssh to the remote cluster and delete the directory that you cloned.

Comment: @vefthym Hi, i am new to hadoop. So how to do that? You mean delete the original directory in GitHub, or ? I am sorry I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an important detail: Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) is a different file system than the local file system of your cluster nodes. The only way to read/write/access HDFS is through hdfs shell commands.

`git clone` does not upload something to hdfs...

You need to ssh to the remote cluster and delete the directory that you cloned, using the shell commands:

```
>ssh username@clusterNodeIP
>rm -r pathOfGitFolder
```

This will remove the git folder from the remote cluster (it was never uploaded to HDFS). If you wanted to upload it to HDFS, you should have used the hadoop shell commands (like hdfs -copyFromLocal) after cloning it.

For more details, I recommend reading:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html
and
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: Thanks so much! it is what I want.